# Get value of an element on Angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, element

I am trying to figure out what is the correct way to get the value of an element in Angular.js.

I am inserting a JSON called options and printing out the values into label tags. The searchStep2 function is supposed to alert the text in the label once a user clicks on it.

My exact code is

```
<li ng-repeat="option in options" >
  <label ng-click="searchStep2()" class="option">{{option}}</label>
</li>
```

In Jquery, I would simply use .text() function to get the value. So my question is what is the equivalent to .text() in Angular.js.

Thanks

Comment: If you really have a need to parse the html, you're probably doing it wrong. Maybe extend your question to include why you need this.

Comment: Just pass the `option` to `searchStep2()`, like `ng-click="searchStep2(option)"`. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi, if you would like to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again